# AEM/CQ - User session will be retained even browser has been closed

Tags: apache, session, aem, jackrabbit-oak

I am looking for an idea to implement that retains user session in AEM 6.X even though browser has been closed. I tried to adjust the Apache Jackrabbit Oak TokenConfiguration - token expiration to a much higher time but still session is not kept when browser has been closed.

However, user is kept when browser is open and you try to close the tab of the application.

I am using google Chrome for testing.

Any ideas on how to implement this approach?

Comment: could you please describe the actual use case? are you trying to prolong the time the user session is kept without the recurring login? Or maybe you're trying to invoke an user-based operation for which your session outdates? or any others?

Comment: Check if this helps: http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/persistent-cookies-used-for.html